# Service Now : transform map stopped due to error: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: servicenow

The transform is getting aborted but only if I marked the checkbox copy empty fields and also the rest of the entry of the Import set is getting stuck at pending, also I verified the transform script but no luck.

Below is the error :

Import set: ISETxxxxxxx transform stopped due to error: java.lang.NumberFormatException

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:596)
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
at com.glide.script.glide_elements.GlideNumber.getSafeBigDecimal(GlideNumber.java:42)
at com.glide.currency.GlideElementCurrency.coerceAmount(GlideElementCurrency.java:406)
at com.glide.currency.GlideElementCurrency.cleanAmount(GlideElementCurrency.java:389)
at com.glide.currency.GlideElementCurrency.setDisplayValue(GlideElementCurrency.java:136)
at com.glide.currency.GlideElementCurrency.setValue(GlideElementCurrency.java:89)
at com.glide.db.impex.transformer.TransformerField.copyEmptyFields(TransformerField.java:202)
at com.glide.db.impex.transformer.TransformerField.setValue(TransformerField.java:130)
at com.glide.db.impex.transformer.TransformerField.transformField(TransformerField.java:84)
at com.glide.db.impex.transformer.TransformRow.transformCurrent(TransformRow.java:100)
at com.glide.db.impex.transformer.TransformRow.transform(TransformRow.java:69)
at com.glide.db.impex.transformer.Transformer.transformBatch(Transformer.java:150)
at com.glide.db.impex.transformer.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:76)
at com.glide.system_import_set.ImportSetTransformerImpl.transformEach(ImportSetTransformerImpl.java:239)
at com.glide.system_import_set.ImportSetTransformerImpl.transformAllMaps(ImportSetTransformerImpl.java:91)
at com.glide.system_import_set.ImportSetTransformer.transformAllMaps(ImportSetTransformer.java:64)
at com.glide.system_import_set.ImportSetTransformer.transformAllMaps(ImportSetTransformer.java:50)
at com.snc.automation.ScheduledImportSetJob.runImport(ScheduledImportSetJob.java:55)
at com.snc.automation.ScheduledImportJob.execute(ScheduledImportJob.java:45)
at com.glide.schedule.JobExecutor.execute(JobExecutor.java:83)
at com.glide.schedule.GlideScheduleWorker.executeJob(GlideScheduleWorker.java:207)
at com.glide.schedule.GlideScheduleWorker.process(GlideScheduleWorker.java:145)
at com.glide.schedule.GlideScheduleWorker.run(GlideScheduleWorker.java:62)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a field that required that is a decimal or similar.

The error `java.lang.NumberFormatException` indicates it's failing to convert an empty string to `0.0`.

Use a source script line to convert this, something along the lines of this

```
answer = (function transformEntry(source) {

    if (source.u_number_field.nil())
        return 0.0;

})(source);
```